# Smoother movement when key is held Keyhandler

Tags: java, key

Every time when I press for example W, my player moves up by 20. But when I hold W, it goes up by 20, waits a second, and then goes up faster.

Is it possible to make my player go up that "fast way" immediately without waiting?

My code:

```java
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) up = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) left = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) down = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) right = true;

    if(up == true){
        if(Main.y == -100){
            return;
        }
        Main.y -= 20;

        Main.frame.repaint();
    }
    if(left == true){
        if(Main.x == -40){
            return;
        }
        Main.x -= 20;
        Main.frame.repaint();
    }
    if(down == true){
        if(Main.y == 440){
            return;
        }
        Main.y += 20;
        Main.frame.repaint();
    }
    if(right == true){
        if(Main.x == 520){
            return;
        }
        Main.x += 20;
        Main.frame.repaint();
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) up = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) left = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) down = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) right = false;
}
```

Comment: Key bindings and a Swing Timer

Comment: On a separate note,  you don' t have to test for `booleans` by comparison.  `if (up == true) {` will evaluate to either `true or false` so why test it?  Just use  `if (up) {` for a `true` test and `if (!up) {` for a `false` test.  But your way will still work if it makes more sense to you.

Comment: Check out the `Keyboard Animation` example found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/). It uses a Swing Timer to schedule the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Having a boolean for each direction, that gets updated when keyPressed() and keyReleased() are called is definitely the right approach. The problem is that keyPressed() also contains your code that moves the player and repaints the frame. You have to put that in some kind of method that repeatedly gets called in a fixed delay, and moves the player depending on which of these booleans are `true`. What I mean is something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /// ...
    while(programIsRunning) {
        movePlayer();
        frame.repaint();
        // let your program sleep here
    }
}

public static void movePlayer() {
    if(up == true){
        if(Main.y == -100){
            return;
        }
        Main.y -= 20;
    }
    if(left == true){
        if(Main.x == -40){
            return;
        }
        Main.x -= 20;
    }
    if(down == true){
        if(Main.y == 440){
            return;
        }
        Main.y += 20;
    }
    if(right == true){
        if(Main.x == 520){
            return;
        }
        Main.x += 20;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) up = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) left = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) down = true;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) right = true;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) up = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) left = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) down = false;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) right = false;
}
```

That way your player should move a lot smoother